# Unable to set key for Menu.Item in antd

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, antd, dnd-kit

Trying to implement drag and drop for menu items in antd.

Individual menu items:

```
function SidebarItem({ item, overlay }: TChildProp) {
  return (
    <Menu.Item
      onClick={(lala) => console.log(lala)}
      style={{ margin: "0px" }}
      key={item.key}
      icon={item.icon}
    >
      {item.label}
    </Menu.Item>
  );
}
```

Adding draggable to the menu item:

```
function DraggableSidebarItem({ item, ...rest }: TChildProp) {
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef } = useDraggable({
    id: uuidv4(),
    data: {
      item,
      fromSidebar: true,
    },
  });

  return (
    <div key={item.key} ref={setNodeRef} {...listeners} {...attributes}>
      <SidebarItem key={item.key} item={item} {...rest} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Using the draggable menu item to render submenu items:

```
function TemplateCreationSideBar() {
  const openMenuKeys: string[] = [
    "Form_Organiser",
    "Form_Components",
    "Input_Types",
  ];

  // Handling addition and removal of sections/components/input types
//   const handleComponentMenuClick = (key: string) => {
//     console.log(key);
//   };
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu
        mode="inline"
        style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
        defaultOpenKeys={openMenuKeys}
        // inlineCollapsed={false}
        // onClick={(item) => {
        //   handleComponentMenuClick(item.key);
        // }}
      >
        {Object.keys(fields).map((parentKey) => {
          return (
            <Menu.SubMenu
              title={fields[parentKey].label}
              key={fields[parentKey].key}
              onTitleClick={(item) => console.log(item)}
              icon={fields[parentKey].icon}
            >
              {fields[parentKey].children?.map((child) => {
                return <DraggableSidebarItem key={child.key} item={child} />;
              })}
            </Menu.SubMenu>
          );
        })}
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, when i click on one item in the menu, all items will be focused/selected. When console.log onClick of each item, the keys are all undefined, hence duplicated.

Errors in console:

Warning: Duplicated key 'undefined' used in Menu by path [Input_Types]

Warning: Duplicated key 'undefined' used in Menu by path [Form_Components]

Comment: What have debugging steps informed you about the value of `fields[parentKey]`? It apparently does not have a `key` value. What does it have? Where does that object come from?

Comment: Hi, 
const fields: Record<string, TMenuItem> = {...}

where 
type TMenuItem = {
  type?: string;
  label: string;
  key: React.Key;
  icon: JSX.Element;
  children?: TMenuItem[];
};

Comment: Also, if you're just using the key to lookup the value in the map, you may be better served using `Object.values(fields).map((field) => `. Then you don't have to do the lookup `fields[parentKey]`, you just use `field`.

Comment: the actual value of fields[parentKey] would be as such. 
{label: 'Components', key: 'Form_Components', icon: {…}, children: Array(5)}

Comment: noted on your suggestion to change `.keys` to `.values`

Comment: Dear future readers, I have resorted to create my own styled components after another day of digging and the drag and drop worked as intended. Do drop your comment in the future when you have found the way to get it to work with <Menu/> or <List/> in antd.